# getting the value of a stylized input in php

Tags: php, css, input

I'm using a CSS3 style for my inputs. The code looks like:

```
<div class="options float-right">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="product_Options[]" />
    <label for="option3"><span></span>Item 1</label>
</div>
<div class="options float-left">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option4" name="product_Options[]" />
    <label for="option4"><span></span>Item 2</label>
</div>
```

When I pass input values through php, I only get this:

on,on

This is my php code:

```
$options = $_POST['product_Options'];

foreach ($options as $opt)
{
    $new_arr[] = $opt;
}
$res_arr = implode(',',$new_arr);
print_r($res_arr);
```

How can I get following result:

Item 1, Item 2

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 3):

Add `value="Item 1"` and `value="Item 2"` to the checkbox inputs.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="product_Options[]" value="Item 1" />
```

Also, given your PHP, just do this instead of looping (it's redundant):

```
$res_arr = implode(',', $_POST['product_Options']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add value attribute -

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option4" name="product_Options[]" value="xyz" />
```